# </sub> symbol in xml file

Tags: python, string

I'm given a txt file with lots of `</sub>`symbols. For example,

> ```
> Influence of Zn on the photoluminescence of colloidal (AgIn)<sub>x</sub>Zn<sub>2(1-x)</sub>S<sub>2</sub> nanocrystals.
> ```

Now I'm trying to use regex to extract the information above to txt file, but my ideal output is

> Influence of Zn on the photoluminescence of colloidal (AgIn)xZn2(1-x)S2 nanocrystals

My current code can only extract the information with lots of `<sub>`, how to get the ideal output?

Comment: "Now I'm trying to use regex to extract the information above to txt file" What tool are you using? What does your regular expression look like?

Comment: I'm using python, my expression is  '(?<=\<ArticleTitle\>)([\s\S]+?)(?=\<\/ArticleTitle\>)'

Comment: I would recommend you try to use an XML parser like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) rather than a brittle regular expression, see this [classic question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is was what you had in mind, but you could use this little Python script I made to print out the lines without the `<sub>` and `</sub>` characters and use the output for further processing.

```
def main():
    remove_list = ['<sub>', '</sub>']

    with open('data.txt') as current_file:
        for i, line in enumerate(current_file):
            for item in remove_list:
                line = line.replace(item, '')
            print(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Just save this code as `main.py` and create a data.txt file in the same directory where you place the xml data.

Run the script as `python3 main.py` to display the output inside the terminal or you could run it as `python3 main.py > output.txt` to append the output to a text file.